# Converse of "$3|a \ and \ 3|b \implies 3|(a+b)$"

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, problem-solving

Here is the implication and my proof :

> $3|a, 3|b \implies 3| a+b$

*Proof:* $a = 3k, b = 3k \implies a + b = 6k = 3(2k)$ and

$\dfrac{3(2k)}3 = 2k$, an integer, which proves the implication.

(should I've used two different variables for instead of k?)

I'm not sure if this is correct but based on this I think that the implication is true.
But then I don't know how to prove the converse of this implication which is

$3|a+b\implies 3|a \ and \ 3|b $

I thought maybe I could use the same method but I have trouble finding the term for the first predicate.

Comment: First, you should have used two different variables for your $k$'s. Then the converse is not true. For example, $3$ divides $2+4$, but $3$ does not divide $2$ nor $4$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial

Comment: yes I know that the converse is not true but how can I prove it?
I dont know if I'm allowed to edit my question but is it correct if I right it like this:
a = 3y.  b = 3x.    a+b = 6xy.    which is 3(2xy)/3 = 2xy that again makes the implication true

Comment: Demonstration of a counterexample proves that a statement is not true

Comment: You only need **one example** to prove the converse is not true. So pick two numbers for $a,b$ that do the job.

Answer (score 1):

if $a=3k+2$ and $b=3j-2$
then $ \qquad 3 \not | a  \qquad  $ and $  \qquad 3 \not | b$
but
$ \qquad a+b=3(k+j) +(2-2)=3(k+j)$
and
$ \qquad 3 | 3(k+j) \implies 3 | (a+b)$